# Saving git metadata when running 'npm run build'

Tags: node.js, git, vue.js, npm

For a project I'm using VueJS, and I have several instances of the application running online  that all derived from the main branch. However, the application may be different because of its commit. Some of them haven't been updated for over year.

What I would like to achieve is: every time I compile my app ('npm run build') i would like to save some metadata about the commit (such as commit hash/date/message) to the dist folder.  I think I would be able to figure that out by writing a bash script or something. But firstly I would like to hear if anyone has done this, maybe some library or best practices? Trying to not reinvent the wheel here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you should update all running instances whenever you release new version of app (maybe not at once, but it is unusual to explicitly want many versions running at once, I think). Or just use versioning in your app, then you would know what version is being run on the instance. Relying on commit id seems very odd.

Comment: @PatrykWlaź In my case, updating is not so easy and might even break the application. It requires time from my side, and it depends if the customer pays for that.

Comment: Actually, versioning makes a lot of sense, you're right. I'm gonna look into that